# Can't using append and appendChild in a jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a sample code:

```
jQuery(document.body).append('<div id="wrapper-1"></div>').appendChild('<div id="wrapper-2"></div>');
```

How to get this result, how to ideas?

```
<div id="wrapper-1">
   <div id="wrapper-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or else you can try this:

```
$('.body').append('<div id="wrapper-1"></div>');
$('<div id="wrapper-2"></div>').appendTo('#wrapper-1');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('body').append('<div id="wrapper-1"><div id="wrapper-2"></div></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
jQuery(document.body).append('<div id="wrapper-1"></div>').children().append('<div id="wrapper-2"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

whats wrong with this?

```
jQuery(document.body).append('<div id="wrapper-1"><div id="wrapper-2"></div></div>');
```

the browser will understand that is a child

Answer (score 0):

`append()` is a jQuery method whereas `appendChild()` is a DOM Element method.

i.e. you need to call `appendChild()` on a pure DOM element. The following should work.

```
jQuery(document.body).append('<div id="wrapper-1"></div>')[0].appendChild('<div id="wrapper-2"></div>');
```

Comment: Error in firebug firefox: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLBodyElement.appendChild]

Answer (score 0):

appendChild() is a javascript native function, while append() is a jquery method. So both in a chain won't work as you expect.

Try this as suggested by Maxim.

```
jQuery('body').append('<div id="wrapper-1"><div id="wrapper-2"></div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var $div1 = $("<div/>");
$div1.attr("id", "wrapper-1");

var $div2 = $("<div/>");
$div2.attr("id", "wrapper-2");

$div1.append($div2);



 <div id="wrapper-1">
    <div id="wrapper-2"></div>
  </div>
```